# Console php version diferent to MAMP on OS X

Tags: php, macos, mamp

I have created a .bash_profile in my home and now it contains the following two lines:

```
export MAMP_PHP=/Application/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.7/bin
export PATH="$MAMP_PHP:$PATH"
```

But the php -v command in the terminal still shows a different version to MAMP. I already restarted both the terminal and MAMP as well.

Any idea?

Comment: what does `echo $PATH` give you in the terminal ?

Comment: Echo PATH displays: /Application/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Comment: now `which php`

Comment: It said: /usr/bin/php

Comment: should not giver what you said. am stomped. Does `which` say the same in a freshly opened terminal window ?

Comment: yes it did, this is what I dont understand